# getLayoutParam returning width as -1

Tags: android

I am trying to set the layout width programatically .

```
 ViewTreeObserver vtoRecyclerView = mMainLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
        vtoRecyclerView.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                mMainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams lpView = mMainLayout.getLayoutParams();
                lpView.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT-20;
                mMainLayout.requestLayout();

            }
        });
```

but  `mMainLayout.getLayoutParams()` is returning *width as -1* .so when I set *width as match_parent - 20* it becomes *-21*. I want to set the `width` as *`match_parent` - 20*.
What is wrong with the approach.

Comment: please check your parent layout or mMainLayout contain width size or not and have any child with any width or not

Answer (score 4):

The root problem with your code here, is because you set the width with:

```
lpView.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT-20;
```

while ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT is a constant.
You can find the constant on ViewGroup class

```
public static final int MATCH_PARENT = -1;
```

So that is obvious, because -1 - 20 is -21

What you can do here is, you can change the line to

```
lpView.width = mMainLayout.getWidth()-20;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

ViewTreeObserver vtoRecyclerView = mMainLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
    vtoRecyclerView.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            mMainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lpView = mMainLayout.getLayoutParams();
            lpView.width = width -20;
            mMainLayout.requestLayout();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   ViewTreeObserver vtoRecyclerView = mMainLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
        vtoRecyclerView.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if(mMainLayout.getWidth > 10 && mMainLayout.getHeight() > 10)  // you can modify this value.
                {
                    mMainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lpView = mMainLayout.getLayoutParams();
                    lpView.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT-20;  // This seems to be wrong;
                    ViewParent parent = mMainLayout.getParent();
                    if(parent != null) {
                        lpView.width = (View)parent.getWidth();
                    }
                    mMainLayout.requestLayout();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while setting width as match_parent, I had resolved this by getting the phone screen width as follows:

```
Display display = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int ActualWidth=width-(`margin you set for view`);
```

Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

As `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` constant predefined numeric value is `-1` so you are getting `-21` as result. and what you want can be achieved by defining `margin` to a layout rather than using that approach.